# SQL Server - different Function results between Management Studio and custom application

Tags: sql-server, user-defined-functions

I have a bizarre problem with an application we use in our company. In this application we have a report tool where you can specify an SQL query, but the problem is: this query gives different results to the **exact same** query ran in SQL Management Studio.

In this query I use a 'Table-valued function', where - I guess - is the main issue, but I just can't see why this would behave differently.

I run the following code (ugly, made to eliminate differences):

```
delete from temptabel;
insert into temptabel ( werknemer, werknemerID, van, vanDatum, tot, activiteit, verlofMethode)
select werknemer, werknemerID, van, vanDatum, tot, activiteit, verlofMethode from TabelVerlofdagen(datefromparts(2018, 05, 01), datefromparts(2018, 05, 31)) order by werknemer, van;
```

If I run this in the SQL Management Studio, it fills the "temptabel" with 219 rows (good!).

If I run the exact same code in the 3rd party softwaer, it fills the "temptabel" with 195 rows (bad!).

How is this possible?

The code from the use table-valued function is the following:

```
USE [Timetell]
GO


SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[TabelVerlofdagen] 
(
    @vanHier Date,
    @totHier Date
)
RETURNS 
@DagenTabel TABLE 
(
    werknemer varchar(50),
    werknemerID int,
    van DateTime, 
    vanDatum DateTime,
    tot DateTime,
    activiteit varchar(50),
    verlofMethode int
)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @verlof_ID INT
    DECLARE DeCursor CURSOR FOR  
    SELECT TT_EMP_BOOK.TT_EMP_BOOK_ID from TT_EMP_BOOK

    OPEN DeCursor   
FETCH NEXT FROM DeCursor INTO @verlof_ID   

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @i INT = (select DAY(TT_EMP_BOOK.TT_TODATE-TT_EMP_BOOK.TT_FROMDATE) 
                          from TT_EMP_BOOK 
                          where (TT_EMP_BOOK.TT_STATUS = 0 or TT_EMP_BOOK.TT_STATUS = 1 or TT_EMP_BOOK.TT_STATUS = 2) 
                          and TT_EMP_BOOK.TT_EMP_BOOK_ID = @verlof_ID and (TT_EMP_BOOK.TT_FROMDATE >= @vanHier or (TT_EMP_BOOK.TT_FROMDATE < @vanHier and TT_EMP_BOOK.TT_TODATE >= @vanHier)))
        WHILE (@i > 0)
        begin
            WITH tempTabel(werknemer, werknemerid, van, vandatum, tot, activiteit, verlofMethode) 
            AS (
                 SELECT TT_EMP.TT_NAME as werknemer, TT_EMP.TT_EMP_ID as werknemerid, TT_EMP_BOOK.TT_FROMDATE as van, dateadd(d, @i-1, TT_EMP_BOOK.TT_FROMDATE) as vandatum,  TT_EMP_BOOK.TT_TODATE as tot, TT_ACT.TT_NAME as activiteit, TT_EMP_BOOK.TT_METHOD as verlofMethode
                 FROM TT_EMP_BOOK, TT_ACT, TT_EMP
                 WHERE TT_ACT.TT_ACT_ID = TT_EMP_BOOK.TT_ACT_ID and  TT_EMP_BOOK.TT_EMP_BOOK_ID = @verlof_ID
                 and TT_EMP_BOOK.TT_EMP_ID = TT_EMP.TT_EMP_ID    )
                 INSERT @DagenTabel
                 SELECT werknemer, werknemerid, van, vandatum, tot, activiteit, verlofMethode
                    FROM tempTabel where vandatum <= @totHier and vandatum >= @vanHier and datepart(dw, vandatum) <> 7 and datepart(dw, vandatum) <> 1 
                    set @i = @i-1
        END
        FETCH NEXT FROM DeCursor INTO @verlof_ID 
    END
    CLOSE DeCursor   
    DEALLOCATE DeCursor
    update @DagenTabel set van = DateAdd(hh, 8, van), tot = DateAdd(hh, 12, tot) where verlofMethode = 6
    update @DagenTabel set van = DateAdd(hh, 13, van), tot = DateAdd(hh, 17, tot) where verlofMethode = 7
    update @DagenTabel set van = DateAdd(hh, 8, vandatum), tot = DateAdd(hh, 17, vandatum) where verlofMethode = 0
    RETURN 

END
GO
```

Comment: A bit tricky to understand cursors w/ temp tables in german, and also we can't reproduce because we don't have the data.  Can you specify which dateformat are you using?(I mean, are you using two differents?) It seems that comparing the dates is causing you some issues (Also mixing Date with DateTime)

Comment: I'd look at the 24 records which are missing from the "bad" set.  What is different?  Any patterns ?

Comment: I would look at getting rid of that cursor. Multi-statement table valued functions are horribly slow. And then you have a cursor with a while loop nested inside of it. Personally I wouldn't put much effort into debugging this. I would put my effort into rewriting this in a set based approach. You will fix the bug along the way to making this a lot better.

Comment: As John said, see which rows are missing.  My guess is there is a datatype that the 3rd party app can't handle moving or transforms into something, such as a dateformat to a string, etc.

Comment: The more I look at this I am 100% confident this could be reworked into  single query instead of looping and all sorts of conditional logic. I would be happy to help you with this but I need some more details to work with. Table structures and some sample data would be a huge help. Here is a great place to get some ideas on how to put that stuff together. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/